# How to write data of a column to output excel from input excel using JAVA POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My Requirement is to read data from input excel file and write it in  output excel file I am using JAVA 8 AND APACHE POI

During the write process I am changing the date format for a particular column from **mm/dd/yyyy** to **dd/mm/yyyy**

With below code its setting current date in excel, I want to set same values of input excel in output excel but with new format defined.

Any help would be really appreciated

Below is **Updated** code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
    import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCreationHelper;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


  class DateFormatDemo1{ 
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, ParseException
    {
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("C:\\DateFormatIssue\\SourceFile\\S.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg); 
        XSSFCreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);      // Create spreadsheet in workbook
        Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
        Cell cell = null;
        Row row=null;
        row=iterator.next();
        int pos=11;
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            row=iterator.next();

            cell= row.getCell(pos-1);


            XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)cell.getCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setDataFormat( createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("M/dd/yyyy")); // set the format of the date  
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");           
            Date d=null;


            /** below if block converts dates which are in format d/M/yyyy (15/04/2017) to M/d/yyyy (4/15/2017)**/
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
            {    

                d= sdf.parse(cell.getStringCellValue());
                cell.setCellValue(d);
                cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);       

            }


            else  if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
            {
                cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue()); 

            }
        }




        FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\DateFormatIssue\\OutputFile\\output.xlsx"));
        wb.write(outFile);
        wb.close();
        outFile.close();
        pkg.close();




    }}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Code executes but column at position 11 it prints 25/4/2017 for all rows. I want to print date which is provided in input file for that column, but with custom formatting provided.

Comment: Ok my mistake! issue is partially solved now. It does prints data of Input file but now issue is I only want to apply custom date format for those dates which are not in d/MM/yyyy rest keep as it is

Comment: Check cell value if it can be parsed with that format, if not, then you set it

Comment: Ok now only 1 issue dates in input file are in multiple format for a column so example, couple of first rows are in M/d/yyyy (1/4/2017) cell type is Date in Excel and remaining are in d/M/yyyy (15/4/2017) cell type is General in Excel. I want one standard format for all rows of (M/d/yyyy) so first rows should look like 4/1/2017 and last rows 4/15/2017.

Comment: i have also posted the updated code.

Comment: You also need to update your requirements/question. `With below code its setting current date in excel` is no longer true and we now don't know what your problem is